# InvalidXMLError: InvalidXMLError: message: "BucketLocationConstraintResult" XML is not parsable

Tags: python, minio, datajoint

I am setting up a local database for datajoint following instructions here: https://github.com/datajoint/mysql-docker.

The mySQL database works but now I wanted to use MinIO for external storage. I fire up MySQL and MinIO as services using docker-compose and set up dj.config for external storage. I am using MinIO service despite running to make it s3 compatible.

Here is my dj.config:

```
dj.config['stores'] = {
    'minio': {  # store in s3
        'protocol': 's3',
        'endpoint': 'minio:9001',
        'bucket': 'test',
        'location': 'test2/',
        'access_key': os.environ.get('MINIO_ROOT_USER', 'FAKEKEY'),
        'secret_key': os.environ.get('MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD', 'FAKEKEY')
    }
}
```

But I get a weird parsing while populating the table. Here is the error stack:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/parsers.py in fromstring(cls, root_name, data)
     68         try:
---> 69             return cls(root_name, ElementTree.fromstring(data.strip()))
     70         except (ParseError, AttributeError, ValueError, TypeError) as error:

/usr/lib/python3.8/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in XML(text, parser)
   1319         parser = XMLParser(target=TreeBuilder())
-> 1320     parser.feed(text)
   1321     return parser.close()

ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidXMLError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-884d9761b97d> in <module>
----> 1 TrainedModel.populate(reserve_jobs=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/autopopulate.py in populate(self, suppress_errors, return_exception_objects, reserve_jobs, order, limit, max_calls, display_progress, *restrictions)
    157                     self.__class__._allow_insert = True
    158                     try:
--> 159                         make(dict(key))
    160                     except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit, Exception) as error:
    161                         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/nnfabrik/templates/trained_model.py in make(self, key)
    273             key["model_state"] = filepath
    274 
--> 275             self.ModelStorage.insert1(key, ignore_extra_fields=True)
    276 
    277 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in insert1(self, row, **kwargs)
    173         For kwargs, see insert()
    174         """
--> 175         self.insert((row,), **kwargs)
    176 
    177     def insert(self, rows, replace=False, skip_duplicates=False, ignore_extra_fields=False, allow_direct_insert=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in insert(self, rows, replace, skip_duplicates, ignore_extra_fields, allow_direct_insert)
    334             return row_to_insert
    335 
--> 336         rows = list(make_row_to_insert(row) for row in rows)
    337         if rows:
    338             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    334             return row_to_insert
    335 
--> 336         rows = list(make_row_to_insert(row) for row in rows)
    337         if rows:
    338             try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in make_row_to_insert(row)
    304             elif isinstance(row, collections.abc.Mapping):  # dict-based
    305                 check_fields(row)
--> 306                 attributes = [make_placeholder(name, row[name]) for name in heading if name in row]
    307             else:  # positional
    308                 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    304             elif isinstance(row, collections.abc.Mapping):  # dict-based
    305                 check_fields(row)
--> 306                 attributes = [make_placeholder(name, row[name]) for name in heading if name in row]
    307             else:  # positional
    308                 try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/table.py in make_placeholder(name, value)
    275                         if attr.is_external:
    276                             # value is hash of contents
--> 277                             value = self.external[attr.store].upload_attachment(attachment_path).bytes
    278                         else:
    279                             # value is filename + contents

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/external.py in upload_attachment(self, local_path)
    199         uuid = uuid_from_file(local_path, init_string=attachment_name + '\0')
    200         external_path = self._make_uuid_path(uuid, '.' + attachment_name)
--> 201         self._upload_file(local_path, external_path)
    202         # insert tracking info
    203         self.connection.query("""

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/external.py in _upload_file(self, local_path, external_path, metadata)
    100     def _upload_file(self, local_path, external_path, metadata=None):
    101         if self.spec['protocol'] == 's3':
--> 102             self.s3.fput(local_path, external_path, metadata)
    103         elif self.spec['protocol'] == 'file':
    104             safe_copy(local_path, external_path, overwrite=True)

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/external.py in s3(self)
     71     def s3(self):
     72         if self._s3 is None:
---> 73             self._s3 = s3.Folder(**self.spec)
     74         return self._s3
     75 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/datajoint/s3.py in __init__(self, endpoint, bucket, access_key, secret_key, secure, **_)
     18                                   secure=secure)
     19         self.bucket = bucket
---> 20         if not self.client.bucket_exists(bucket):
     21             raise errors.BucketInaccessible('Inaccessible s3 bucket %s' % bucket) from None
     22 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/api.py in bucket_exists(self, bucket_name)
    402 
    403         try:
--> 404             self._url_open('HEAD', bucket_name=bucket_name)
    405             return True
    406         except NoSuchBucket:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/api.py in _url_open(self, method, bucket_name, object_name, query, body, headers, content_sha256, preload_content)
   2183 
   2184         # Get bucket region.
-> 2185         region = self._get_bucket_region(bucket_name)
   2186 
   2187         # Construct target url.

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/api.py in _get_bucket_region(self, bucket_name)
   2061         region = self._region or self._region_map.get(bucket_name)
   2062         if not region:
-> 2063             region = self._get_bucket_location(bucket_name)
   2064             self._region_map[bucket_name] = region
   2065         return region

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/api.py in _get_bucket_location(self, bucket_name)
   2105             raise ResponseError(response, method, bucket_name).get_exception()
   2106 
-> 2107         location = parse_location_constraint(response.data)
   2108         # location is empty for 'US standard region'
   2109         if not location:

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/parsers.py in parse_location_constraint(data)
    425     :return: Returns location of your bucket.
    426     """
--> 427     root = S3Element.fromstring('BucketLocationConstraintResult', data)
    428     return root.text()
    429 

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/minio/parsers.py in fromstring(cls, root_name, data)
     69             return cls(root_name, ElementTree.fromstring(data.strip()))
     70         except (ParseError, AttributeError, ValueError, TypeError) as error:
---> 71             raise InvalidXMLError(
     72                 '"{}" XML is not parsable. Message: {}'.format(
     73                     root_name, error

InvalidXMLError: InvalidXMLError: message: "BucketLocationConstraintResult" XML is not parsable. Message: syntax error: line 1, column 0
```

Comment: It would help us to see more of your jupyter notebook, trained_model.py, and docker compose file so that we could try to reproduce this locally. It may be a config issue, but it's hard to tell from what's here. \\ In the meantime, you might take a look at our compose file here: https://github.com/datajoint/datajoint-python/blob/master/LNX-docker-compose.yml#L16-L26

Comment: Hi @user72328 - Were you able to track down the source of this error?